# Select User.Identify.Name using Code Blocks

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a SqlDataSource SelectCommand on my .aspx page.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserResult]"
     OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This statement will grep a list of data from the table `UserResult`.

However I would only want to list specific results which belongs to the user.

I have attached a column in the `UserResult` table which is `username`, and I tried to form an sql statement like this but it seems to search for user `User.Identity.nAME` :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SODConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserResult] WHERE [username] LIKE 'User.Identity.Name'";"
     OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

May I know how can I do it?

**Update:**

From solution from Curt, I have tried to implement the following:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SODConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserResult] WHERE [username]=@username"
     OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" DefaultValue='<%=User.Identity.Name %>' />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

However I am still not able to retrieve data according to the username.

I tried to hard code a username into the `username` parameter and it worked:

Anyone could help?

```
<asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" DefaultValue="james" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is looking for `User.Identity.Name` because this is set as a string.

Try using code blocks:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SODConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserResult] WHERE [username]=@username"
     OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" DefaultValue='<%=User.Identity.Name %>' />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[Embedded Code Blocks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx)

Comment: @Curt thank you, but my datagrid still display empty data despite changing my code to yours.

Comment: @Curt if I change the `DefaultValue` to a fix username, the datagrid shows

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to declare a Default Value in `.aspx` file. You can only add to the code behind file.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["UserName"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;
}
```